# Is Rules Engine a right choice for implementing fraud rules?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, rule-engine

I'm building an enterprise application which has fraud rules. The rules will be based on a matrix, for example, how many times a user used this service in a month, is the total transaction amount exceeds a certain amount, what funding source does he use, etc?

Is rules engine the right choice for implementing fraud rules? What is the right choice for a Java EE6 application running in glassfishV3? And my boss doesn't want to spend money on it unfortunately, so has to be open source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It really "depends", Have a look at Drools: http://www.jboss.org/drools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enterprise business rules engine (BRE) would be the appropriate place to capture and evaluate fraud rules. If you're going use open-source Java EE, I've seen [JBoss Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/) work well for several clients. In addition, based upon your requirements, you might also want to consider some type of event stream processing to allow real-time fraud flagging. The only open-source product I've seen in this space is [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/), although a bunch of other COTS (Commercial-Off-the-Shelf,) tools you may already have in place are being re-calibrated to address this need as well.